# What does it mean to have a rare ring to something?

Tags: expressions, meaning

I was reading a book and came across the following (emphasis was mine)

> Those words **have a rare ring to them**, don’t they?

What is the meaning of the expression in bold?

Comment: Dictionary.com defines **ring** thus: _the aspect or impression presented by a statement, an action, etc., taken as revealing a specified inherent quality_ That's what it means in your sentence.

Comment: See [this NGram chart,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=words+have+an+unusual+ring%2Cwords+have+a+rare+ring%2Cwords+have+a+familiar+ring&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwords%20have%20a%20familiar%20ring%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cwords%20have%20a%20familiar%20ring%3B%2Cc0) showing that by far the most common type of "ring" that words might have is *a **familiar** ring* (the words sound like something you've heard before). Using ***rare*** here is very uncommon, very "poetic", *and* very "dated".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part **rare** has the typical meaning **unusual**.

The second part **ring** is given by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/ring) as

> **ring²**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> **2** A particular quality conveyed by something heard or expressed.
> *the song had a curious ring of nostalgia to it*

The dictionary example is similar to the question's sentence.